# C++ unusual socket behaviour

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a music streaming application using a TCP server - client connection. In order to achieve the song being played by the client, I need to transfer specific data from the server such as the file's channels, average bytes per second, etc. The connection is successful when downloading the song list from the server or sending a hello message, however when trying to use the recv() function to get the file's average bytes per second for example, the client stops when reaching that part. It doesn't receive any data and does not proceed to other commands.

To make it easier to understand the "protocol" of the data exchange, the client program starts two threads, one which sends the request to the Server (SendRequests function) and one which receives data sent from it (Receive function). Since this issue has not appeared in any other part of the program I am completely lost as to what to do.

Client SendRequests function:

```
DWORD sendRequests = WaitForSingleObject(threadMutex, INFINITE);
_commandType = commandType;

//std::cout << "TYPE: " << _commandType << std::endl;
if (_commandType == 0)
    DefineMenu(1);
else if (_commandType == 1) // sends a hello msg to the server; for testing purposes
{
    char sendString[1024] = "H - Hello from client: ";

    int len = send(_activeSocket, sendString, sizeof(sendString), 0);
    if (len == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "len socket error" << std::endl;
        _isActive = 0;
    }
}
else if (_commandType == 2) // requests the most updated list
{
    char sendString[1024] = "L - Requesting the most updated list. \n";
    int len = send(_activeSocket, sendString, sizeof(sendString), 0);
    if (len == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "len socket error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        _isActive = 0;
    }
}
// determines if the user chose any number (of a track) from the list to start streaming
else if (_commandType == 3)
{

    if (_storedList.empty() == false)
    {

        int userinput = std::stoi(_userinput);
        bool isIndexed = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _storedList.size(); i++)
        {
            if (userinput == i)
            {
                isIndexed = true;
            }
        }

        if (isIndexed)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _totalCount; i++)
            {
                if (userinput == i)
                {
                    _selectedTrack = _storedList[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            std::wcout << "You selected: " << _selectedTrack << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Preparing it for playback..." << std::endl;

            std::string select = selectSong(_userinput);

            if (select != "No song") {
                int len = send(_activeSocket, select.c_str(), 1024, 0);

                std::cout << select << std::endl;
                if (len == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    std::cout << "len socket error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                    _isActive = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong index!" << std::endl;
        }
        //Sleep(1000);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty." << std::endl;
    }

    //Sleep(1000);
}
else if (_commandType == 4) {
char sendString[1024] = "N - Requesting Audio File Stream. \n";
int len = send(_activeSocket, sendString, sizeof(sendString), 0);
if (len == SOCKET_ERROR)
 {
    std::cout << "len socket error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    _isActive = 0;
 }
}
else
{
    _commandType = 0;
}


ReleaseMutex(threadMutex);
```

Client Receive function:

```
while (_isActive == 1)
{

    try
    {

        if (_commandType == 1)
        {
            char recvMSG[1024];
            int length = recv(_activeSocket, recvMSG, 1024, NULL);
            if (length <= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "\nReceive has failed. Error that occured: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                //_isActive = 0;
                break;
                //SendRequests(0);
            }

            std::cout << recvMSG << std::endl;

        }

        if (_commandType == 2)
        {
            wchar_t newList[1024];
            int length = recv(_activeSocket, (char*)newList, 48, NULL);
            if (length <= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "\nReceive has failed. Error that occured: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                _isActive = 0;
                break;
            }

            std::wstring serialList = newList;

            std::vector<std::wstring> newVecList = Split(serialList, '|');

            std::cout << std::endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < newVecList.size(); i++)
            {
                std::wcout << "[" << i << "] " << newVecList[i] << std::endl;
                _totalCount += i;
            }

            _storedList = newVecList;
        }
            
        if (_commandType == 3)
        {
            std::cout << "Command 3 has started" << std::endl;

            wchar_t recvMSG[1024];
            //int length = recv(_activeSocket, (char*)recvMSG, 1024, NULL);

            //std::cout << length << std::endl;
            //if (length <= 0)
            if(ReceiveData((char*)recvMSG, sizeof(recvMSG)) == false) //This recv() is the one mentioned above
            {
                std::cout << "\nReceive has failed. Error that occured: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                _isActive = 0;
                break;
                SendRequests(0);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Warning" << std::endl;
            }

        std::wstring trackInfo = recvMSG;

        std::wcout << trackInfo << std::endl;

            DefineMenu(2);

        }
        if (_commandType == 4) {
            char recvMSG[1024];
            int length = recv(_activeSocket, recvMSG, 1024, NULL);
            if (length <= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "\nReceive has failed. Error that occured: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
                //_isActive = 0;
                break;
                //SendRequests(0);
            }

            std::cout << "Streaming has started!" << std::endl;

        }
        
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "\nError was Caught: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

ReceiveData function:

```
int bytesreceived = 0; 
while (bytesreceived < totalbytes)
{
    int ReceiveCheck = recv(_activeSocket, data + bytesreceived, totalbytes - bytesreceived, NULL);
    if (ReceiveCheck == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        return false;
    else if (ReceiveCheck == -1) {
        std::cout << errno << std::endl;
    }
    bytesreceived += ReceiveCheck;
}
return true;
```

Server side:

```
std::cout << "Client Connected!" << std::endl;

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        char recvMSG[1024];
        int packetLength = recv(_clientSocket, recvMSG, sizeof(recvMSG), NULL);
        if (packetLength <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error receiving command: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            DeleteServer(this);
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Client " << int(this) << " sent " << recvMSG[0] << std::endl;

        if (recvMSG[0] == 'H')
        {   
            char _sendString[1024] = "\nHello from WAV streamer!\n";

            std::cout << recvMSG << int(this) << std::endl;
            send(_clientSocket, _sendString, sizeof(_sendString), 0);
        }
        if (recvMSG[0] == 'L')
        {
            _playList = GetTheList();

            std::wstring serialList;

            for (int i = 0; i < _playList.size(); i++)
            {
                serialList = serialList + _playList[i] + L'|';
            }

            std::cout << recvMSG << std::endl;
            std::wcout << serialList << std::endl;
            send(_clientSocket, (char*)serialList.c_str(), sizeof(serialList) + 16, 0);
            std::cout << sizeof(serialList) << std::endl;
        }
        if (recvMSG[0] == '1' || recvMSG[0] == '2') {

            std::cout << "Client requested song: " << recvMSG[0] << " info" << std::endl;
            _playList = GetTheList();

            const size_t cSize = strlen(recvMSG) + 1;
            wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
            mbstowcs(wc, recvMSG, cSize);


            if (((wc == _selectedTrack) || (wc != _selectedTrack)) && (_selectedTrack != L"" || wc != L""))
                //if ( ( (recvMSG == _selectedTrack) || (recvMSG != _selectedTrack)) && (_selectedTrack != L"" || recvMSG != L"") )
            {
                std::string::size_type sz;

                _selectedTrack = wc;
                int point = std::stoi(_selectedTrack, &sz) - 1;
    
                //recvMSG;

                //Call method to get the file size in bytes and prepare it for streaming
                std::wstring name = getFileName(point, "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Storage\\*.wav");

                DirectSoundLoad mainLoader(name);

                std::string trackInfo = "\nFile name: ";

                std::cout << trackInfo;

                std::wcout << name << endl;

                trackInfo = "Average Bytes Per Second:" + std::to_string(mainLoader.getAvgBPS());
                
                std::cout << trackInfo << endl;

                std::string toSend = std::to_string(mainLoader.getAvgBPS());

                std::cout << "Sending message:" << toSend.c_str() << std::endl;
                
                
                //SendData(toSend.c_str(), sizeof(toSend));

                int songData = send(_clientSocket, toSend.c_str(), sizeof(toSend), 0);
            
            }
            else
            {
                std::string trackInfo = "\nSorry, this file doesn't exist in the list anymore.";
                send(_clientSocket, trackInfo.c_str(), 1024, 0);
            }
        }
        recvMSG[0] = '\0';
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "An error has occured." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    
}
```

I'm sorry for the long post and I would be really thankful if anyone could actually help me out.

P.S. I know the code is a bit messy and could use some improvements.

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand, but since time is of the essence since I've been stuck on this part for a week and the deadline is getting closer and the previous exchanges of data seem to work, I don't understand why this one shouldn't. It's a simple string being sent.

Comment: Seems there is a bug somewhere.  Make a small toy program that communicates between two processes on the same or different computer.  Hopefully that helps you identify where your logic is going awry in your actual program.  If the logic is also going awry in your toy program, post that source code here so we can help.  The code snippets provided are insufficient for me to guess as to what is wrong, since I'd like to step through the code, and the provided code is not a [mcve].

Comment: @Eljay I will try to do so to see where the issue is. However, I tried using the select() function for debugging reasons which returns a connection timeout. Does this add any detail to the problem?

Comment: *Does this add any detail to the problem?*  Does it allow me to take your code, compile your code, execute your code, attach a debugger, step through your code line-by-line to see what's going on?

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for the info. Would it be considered a plausible solution to adjust the amount of received bytes based on those sent by the server?

Comment: @Eljay I understand, but due to the volume of the code itself and the different files included, I think it would be hard to upload the whole thing and I can't expect anyone to go through the trouble of running and debugging it for me.

Comment: I think you may have missed the part about *"Make a small toy program..."*

Comment: Could you use Wireshark to see if the data is actually sent from the server? I suspect it is being buffered at the server side and not being sent to the client at all.

Comment: @Eljay there's not much to minify from two programs that require 4 .h and 4.cpp files each, plus a couple of .wav files in order to just provide the minum desired functionality though. But I will try. Thanks again.

Comment: Another way of checking that would be closing the connection at the server side right after the data (which is not received by client) is written to the socket. This would also force the data to be sent.

Comment: @Cem Didn't even know that such an app even existed. I will give it a try. Thanks!